# Finding transitive closure

Tags: relations

Answer the following, related to the relation $R$ on domain $D$, where $D = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and
$R=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (4,3), (3,4), (5,4), (4,5), (5,2), (2,4)\}$:
List the elements in the transitive closure of $R$.

This is my answer: $R= \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (4,3), (3,4), (5,4), (4,5), (5,2), (2,4), (3,5), (5,3),(4,2), (2,3),( 2,5), (3,2)\}$
I just want to know I miss anything

Answer (score 1):

We have $5R2R4R3R4R5$, so we know everything other than $1$ is related to each other (except potentially themselves, but that's handled by $R$ being reflexive). We can see that $1$ is only related to itself, so the transitive closure won't make it relate to anything else. That is indeed what your answer is saying (though maybe call the transitive closure something different).